# How do you select lower and uppercase characters in a string using an if-else statement in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to solve a problem where I wish to select multiple words beginning with 's', but have both the lowercase and uppercase words be shown in the output.

To try and achieve my desired result, I used an if-else statement in a for-loop but it only selected the first value I chose. For example, if I wrote 'S' first, it selected the uppercase and ignored the lowercase.

```
st = 'Sally sells shakes from Shake Shack every Saturday.'

for i in st.split():
 if i[0] == 's' and 'S':
        print(i)
```

I expected the output to be:
sells
shakes
Sally
Shake
Shack
Saturday

But the actual output was:
sells
shakes

Comment: To explain: `if i[0] == 's' and 'S':` gives you two Booleans: `(i[0] == 's')` checks if this relation is true, and `'S'` checks if 'S' (which defaults to True). So in this example, the first clause is only true when the word starts with 's' and the second clause is always true, hence the result.

Comment: Here is a table on operator precedence in python that might be useful. It's like BEDMAS or PEMDAS, except with more operators: http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lower()` to make comparison lowercase:

```
st = 'Sally sells shakes from Shake Shack every Saturday.'

for i in st.split():
    if i.lower().startswith('s'):
        print(i)
```

result:

```
Sally
sells
shakes
Shake
Shack
Saturday.
```

Answer (score 1):

use logical **OR**: Return True if one of the statements are True : Your word will start with 'S' or 's'

NOTE: i[0] == 's' and 'S', is not correct expression in this case

STATEMENT1: i[0] == 's'

STATEMENT2: i[0] == 'S'

if STATEMENT1 or STATEMENT2

```
st = 'Sally sells shakes from Shake Shack every Saturday.'

for i in st.split():
   if i[0] == 's' or i[0] == 'S':
       print(i)
```